# What can experienced SE users who are new to RPGs bring to the community?

Tags: discussion

I'm a user of multiple stackExchanges and have a few k rep in a few different SEs.

I started playing RPGs last year, so I'm aware my experience is pretty vanilla so far (Pathfinder and about to start some games of Paranoia).

I'm enjoying asking questions and answering but since the scope of rpg.se is "experts helping experts", should I lurk moar before answering since my answers are likely to be filtered through the prism of new-gm and new-player in limited systems?

I'm happy for my answers to languish without votes, but I don't want to muddy the waters with my enthusiasm to participate.

What's best for the community from users who grok SE, but are new to RPGs?

Answer (score 14):

**Real questions to specific problems after you've done some research.**

We like real and *non-trivial* questions. When asking a question, make sure you've done your research. Look it up on google, ask for us to help you shape it in chat.

But if it's a problem that you're facing and the answer is non-obvious, we'd love to have your question.

Answer (score 8):

Also, answering questions by *other* new players/GMs is something that's absolutely OK. I probably have *less* experience with Pathfinder than you do, but [anyone with a bit of experience in a d20 game can look up and clarify rules in the SRD](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/armor-as-dr-alternate-rules-do-untyped-ac-bonuses-apply-to-defense-or-dr). If you spot an easy "gimme" question like that, where the asker is missing something more-or-less obvious but an well-written answer can make it clear, and you know where and how to get that info, go for it. They often won't garner much rep (I think because people don't consider "reading comprehension" questions interesting and so they don't even look, let alone vote), but a bit here and there adds up.

Generally, if you confidently know the answer, it's safe to give it. *Sometimes* you'll get it wrong and someone will completely school you – it'll feel a bit embarrassing, but there's no actual shame in being corrected and maybe deleting a wrong answer. (It's actually fairly respected as humbly doing the right thing, and [they give out a badge for it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/badges/20/peer-pressure). Besides, I've experienced this several times here myself, despite 20 years of RPG experience!) More often than not, you'll be right and it'll be helpful. Let confidence be your guide more than enthusiasm, and it will not often steer you wrong.

Comment: Well put, especially about using rules resources.

Comment: And yet, one of those "reading comprehension" questions is the one from which I got the most rep to date.

Comment: @Nigralbus Yep, there are exceptions!

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't hesitate to post, the community will let you know either via comments or votes if something is wrong. Worst case you ask a question that doesn't fit the guidelines and you delete it. This hands back the rep you lost and people spent voting you down.

My first few questions and answers on RPG.SE weren't perfect and people let me know. I was able to salvage some, but others I scuttled and kept the knowledge of the experience with me as I moved forward to write better questions and answers.